# Error creating bean with name flywayInitializer defined in class path resource

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

Estou tentando adicionar novos campos na minha tabela no meu projeto Spring Boot utilizando Flyway, sendo que não estou conseguindo e estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro.

```
2020-04-29 12:53:36.345  WARN 544 --- [  restartedMain]
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed:  Migration
checksum mismatch for migration version 02
-> Applied to database : 0
-> Resolved locally    : -1105036925

2020-04-29 12:53:36.346  INFO 544 --- [  restartedMain]
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
initiated... 2020-04-29 12:53:36.347  INFO 544 --- [  restartedMain]
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
completed. 2020-04-29 12:53:36.350  INFO 544 --- [  restartedMain]
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-29 12:53:36.359  INFO 544 --- [  restartedMain]
ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-04-29 12:53:36.366
ERROR 544 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication            
: Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed:  Migration
checksum mismatch for migration version 02
-> Applied to database : 0
-> Resolved locally    : -1105036925

    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]  at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]   at
com.server.agenda.AgendaApplication.main(AgendaApplication.java:10)
[classes/:na]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
~[na:1.8.0_241]     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
~[na:1.8.0_241]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
~[na:1.8.0_241]     at
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE] Caused by:
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed:  Migration
checksum mismatch for migration version 02
-> Applied to database : 0
-> Resolved locally    : -1105036925

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:275)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:79)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:157)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:149)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:511)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149)
~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]     at
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65)
~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     ... 23 common frames
omitted
```

A estrutura do projeto está correto, os arquivos estão nomeados corretos, o script de sql está também certo, não sei onde está o problema, observem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu banco de dados é o **Postgre**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou responder essa pergunta com base no título que você colocou e com base no fato de você está tentando adicionar novos campos na tabela:

Se você está sempre alterando o mesmo script depois de já ter rodado o projeto e criado as tabelas e o **flyway_schema_history**, você precisa:

- ou deletar todas as tabelas e rodar novamente
- ou você apaga os dados da tabela **flyway_schema_history**.

Answer (score 0):

Para limpar os dados de tabela **flyway_schema_history** pode eliminar Docker imagens no computador e instalar novamente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Cada vez que você da um run na aplicação e sua versão do flyway foi modificada, é gerado uma nova versão no flyway_schema_history no seu banco, quando você altera uma versão que ja rodou na sua aplicação e tenta roda-la novamente, retorna erro pois aquela versão já existe, por isso sempre que for alterar, aconselho a criar uma nova versão e ai colocar a aplicação para rodar o mais indicado se fez isso é ir no banco e deletar todas as tabelas e rodar novamente para o erro parar de acontecer.

Comment: Quando for colocar uma pergunta, sempre faça ela completa. Colocar como resposta a sua continuação complica a visualização de quem possa poder te ajudar